# VPN - Home LAN to office LAN

Tags: networking, vpn, lan

I'm not exactly sure of what equipment I need to do this and any help would be appreciated. I'm the guy supposed to looking after the equipment, but VPN is an unknown territory for me.

I want to:

1. Map a drive to a folder on one of the office servers.
2. Be able to connect with a browser or Telnet to any of the office's
   servers and equipments.

The idea is that some people work from home and must be able to fetch files from the server (case 1). These are people with "no" computer skills and it would be ideal if the VPN was connecting automatically as soon they open the Mapped drive. Is this possible?

For myself, I need to use case 2 to monitor/configure all the equipment in the office. In my own case I have my own LAN with routers, servers and clients. For me the ideal would be if the office's LAN looked and felt like a local LAN to me where only access to the office goes through VPN and everything else goes out by my ISP (not over VPN and then out to internet from the office).

My guess is that I need to get some VPN/Firewall equipment in the office and home. Everyone else could use the built in VPN in Windows?

Both LANs (my own and office) have registered domain names with static IP.

Comment: You can do VPN via hardware or software(openvpn).  The trick, is the hardware is going to be rated for a certain number of users(and that number maybe over stated), and if you ever go above that you need to buy a bigger more expensive unit.  The firewalls will have to be configured to allow it, obviously.  Loading OpenVPN onto a standard PC makes upgrading easier.  Typically they will state one number of supported users, but if you want the best encryption, you read the fine print, and its half that many users.

Comment: I read that OpenVPN and the built in VPN client in Windows don't like each other, so I think I will go for hardware, but how does it work? I guess teh VPN licenses are simultaneously VPN connections, not bound to a specific user?

Comment: Do not go for the Windows VPN. They only support PPTP (broken since 2012 - cracking a connection costs ~200 USD), L2TP/IPSec with DES (old and considered insecure now) or 3DES (slow, old, maybe secure) and SSTP which can only use TCP.

Comment: What VPN protocols are considered to be good today?

Comment: @MaxKielland   https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides-sp-859543150/howto-connect-client-configuration/395-how-to-install-the-openvpn-client-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VPN is a good solution for your problem. The drawback is that VPN has a lot of pitfalls when it comes to security; VPN can exist (and be useful in some cases) without any encryption of the transferred data.

### How many people will use the VPN simultaneously?

There are many solutions for small and medium companies which are quite easy to use. But they are (often) limited to a small amount of concurrent users (like 12, 24, or 32 users). Better/Unlimited solutions can be more difficult to set up.

Also, if you have many concurrent users you have to think about performance and bandwidth requirements of your WAN connection etc.

### Server side: software solution

There are many software VPN solutions available. You can set them up on a Linux machine or use a VM or a dedicated server.

[OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) is a well known open source software. There are virtually dozens of tutorials (also YouTube videos) on how to set it up. There are clients for many platforms (i used it in Linux, Windows and Android). Maybe you want to use this for starters.

[pfSense](https://www.pfsense.org/) is full featured firewall. Maybe overkill, but more feature rich than OpenVPN. There are also many tutorials out there.

There are many many more ...

### Server side: hardware solution

You could also go ahead an buy a Router with VPN. Most of the known manufacturers offer one and they all provide the client software. Maybe your router already supports VPN?

This is usually easier to set up but also has its limits. The limitations vary between products and manufacturer.

### Configuration

Do you use IPv4 or IPv6 or both? If you use IPv6 you need to pay special attention to your firewall configuration or else traffic might circumvent your encrypted VPN tunnel.

Independent of which solution you choose you will have to think about the configuration, which in this case means mostly about IP routing.

There are three basic types of VPN:
end-to-end

- **end-to-end**: a connection between both hosts. Nothing else can communicate through the tunnel.
- **end-to-site**: (also known as remote-dial-in) here a remote host can access the full network through the VPN tunnel. This is probably what you want
- **site-to-site**: (also known as LAN-to-LAN). This connects two independent LANs with each other. For the LANs it looks like they are using a router (as usual). The routers on each side then do the tunnelling via the Internet.

Comment: I think I want a hardware solution because then I can reach the network even if the server is down (for example restart it from the UPS). We use IPv4 and while site-to-site is the solution for me, end-to-end would probably be enough for those who needs to access files from the server. But still, can they connect automatically by opening a mapped folder? I guess some routing tables has to be added in each client.

Comment: Might be possible but it is probably hard. I would provide them with a simple batch file which (1) establishes VPN connection and then (2) (re-)connects the mapped drive. For (2) you can use the command `net use`